# Get Top 10 Purchases from all users of my woocommerce shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im playing around with some querys and I just created a shortcode which does get me the top 10 purchases in my woocommerce shop and displays name price and ranking in a list. It works perfectly fine, but I have no idea if it is best practise and/or safe. Can somebody confirm my solution and/or edit it?

Thanks in advance!

```
function topranking(){

    // WOOCOMMERCE QUERY TOP 10
    $query   = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'limit'      => 10,
        'orderby'    => 'price',
        'status'     => 'completed',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'return'     => 'ids',
    ) );
    $orders  = $query->get_orders();

    $total_amount = array();
    $count = 0;

    foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
        $order                            = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $total_amount[ $order_id ]        = $order->get_total();
        $billing_first_name [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_last_name  [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $count++;
        ?>
            <p><?php echo $count ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $total_amount[ $order_id ] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $billing_first_name [ $order_id ] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $billing_last_name [ $order_id ] ?></p>      
        <?php
    }
 }
add_shortcode('top', 'topranking');
```

Comment: I'm surprised it's actually showing what you want, since you have to return shortcode output rather than echo it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the code itself is safe and fine? What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things.

1. Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.
2. escape your output.

```
<?php
function topranking(){

    // WOOCOMMERCE QUERY TOP 10
    $query   = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'limit'      => 10,
        'orderby'    => 'price',
        'status'     => 'completed',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'return'     => 'ids',
    ) );
    $orders  = $query->get_orders();

    $total_amount = array();
    $count = 0;
    // If you want to echo your output... use output buffering
    ob_start();
    foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
        $order                            = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $total_amount[ $order_id ]        = $order->get_total();
        $billing_first_name [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_last_name  [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $count++;
        ?>
        <p><?php echo esc_html($count); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo esc_html($total_amount[ $order_id ]); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo esc_html($billing_first_name [ $order_id ]); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo esc_html($billing_last_name [ $order_id ]); ?></p>
        <?php
    }
    // Return shortcode output.
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('top', 'topranking');
```

**or using concatenation**

```
function topranking() {

    // WOOCOMMERCE QUERY TOP 10
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'limit'   => 10,
        'orderby' => 'price',
        'status'  => 'completed',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'return'  => 'ids',
    ) );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    $total_amount = array();
    $count = 0;
    // Instead of output buffer - set $output to empty string
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $total_amount[$order_id] = $order->get_total();
        $billing_first_name [$order_id] = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_last_name  [$order_id] = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $count++;

        $output .= '<p>' . esc_html( $count ) . '</p>';
        $output .= '<p>' . esc_html( $total_amount[$order_id] ) . '</p>';
        $output .= '<p>' . esc_html( $billing_first_name [$order_id] ) . '</p>';
        $output .= '<p>' . esc_html( $billing_last_name [$order_id] ) . '</p>';
        
    }
    // Return shortcode output.
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'top', 'topranking' );
```

Comment: thank you very much for the great explanation!

Comment: This code does not bring the "top 10 sales", it only brings the last 10 orders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74464802/create-a-ranking-leaderboard-of-customers-in-woocommerce-based-in-price-total