# Create a Ranking/Leaderboard of customers in WooCommerce based in price total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a ranking/leaderboard of the best customers of a WooCommerce store, based on the amount that these customers spent. I even found this link [Get Top 10 Purchases from all users of my woocommerce shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783107/get-top-10-purchases-from-all-users-of-my-woocommerce-shop)

Both the question code and the answer given as correct are incorrect, because both do not return the "top 10 sales", they only return the last 10 sales, regardless of the value. Looking at the WooCommerce documentation link at https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query there is no "'orderby' => 'price'," to return orders based on total amount.

I needed a similar solution but that really was the "top 10 biggest sales", so I thought of printing custom attributes of the values ​​in the HTML and then manipulating the order with JavaScript, but then I would have the "Limit" problem since I If I only looked for the last 10 orders, and in my store there were 100+ orders, several of them would even enter the query.

So I thought of creating a customer loop, and then fetching orders from each one of them, but that wouldn't solve it either, since some orders are from visiting customers.

the code below is an example of this implementation (does not work)

```
<?php function topranking($atts){

    $qtd = 10;

    if($atts["qtd"]):
       $qtd = $atts["qtd"];
    endif;

   // WOOCOMMERCE QUERY TOP 10
   $query   = new WC_Order_Query( array(
     'limit'      =>  $qtd,
     'orderby'    => 'price',
     'status'     => array( 'processing','completed' ),
     'order'      => 'DESC',
     'return'     => 'ids',
   ) );
   $orders  = $query->get_orders();

   $total_amount       = array();
   $billing_first_name = array();
   $billing_last_name  = array();
   $billing_email      = array();

   $count = 0;
   // If you want to echo your output... use output buffering
  ob_start();
  
  foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
  
    $order                            = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $total_amount[ $order_id ]        = $order->get_total();
    $billing_first_name [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $billing_last_name  [ $order_id ] = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $billing_email  [ $order_id ]     = $order->get_billing_email();
    $count++;
    ?>
    <p><?php echo esc_html($count); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo number_format($total_amount[ $order_id ],2,",","."); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo esc_html($billing_first_name [ $order_id ]); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo esc_html($billing_last_name [ $order_id ]); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo esc_html($billing_email [ $order_id ]); ?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php
  }
  // Return shortcode output.
  return ob_get_clean();
  }

  add_shortcode('top', 'topranking'); ?>
```

What would be the smart way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it odd of me to think you might like to write the code to do this yourself or at least modify this code thats quite close to what you want **yourself**, rather than complaining about not being able to copy/paste someone elses code that does exactly what you want? You do claim to be a "Programador e Designer" afterall

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you've read my question, the problem is that I haven't found a correct approach to fetch WooCommerce orders based on total order value. And it's not a third-party code complaint, it's a finding that there is an error, but I'm going to assume that you just didn't read what was written correctly,